# SSH socks proxy server on by default

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

I need some help with SOCKS proxy server based on SSH.

I am running SSH SOCKS proxy using this command:

```
ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost
```

Can I somehow enable it by default? The ssh deamon is on by default anyways, so there must be a way to configure it.

Also, I am using 0.0.0.0 to allow all incomming ip addresses. Can I limit it to a subnet? For example 192.168.1.0/24. Or maybe at least an interface name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### setup key based authentication

As a prerequisite you need to set up your SSH connection to use key based authentication so that the connection works without a password.

Copy your publickey to the remote machine:

```
ssh-copy-id remoteuser@remotehost
```

Test the key based authentication:

```
ssh remoteuser@remotehost
```

If the SSH connection succeeds **without asking you for a password**, you can proceed.

---

#### create systemd service

Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/` called `yourtunnel.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH socks proxy
After=network-online.target
[Service]
User=your_user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost
ExecStop=kill $(pgrep -f 'ssh -N -D')
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable --now yourtunnel.service` and check if the service started successfully with `sudo systemctl status yourtunnel.service`

---

#### restricting access to allow only specific IP addresses

You'll need to setup firewall rules, as the IP address in your command only specifies the address of the interface on your local machine to which SSH binds.

**Example with UFW:**

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  192.168.1.0/24 to any port 1080
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I have added a specific interface address, in my case 10.6.0.4, instead of 0.0.0.0. I assume this should limit it only to packets coming on interface that has 10.6.0.4, which is in my case enough.

Comment: mashuptwice thanks again for your help.
Do you have any idea about how the same can be done in a docker container? I checked a couple of sshd containers, however when i executed the command inside the container i received "Permission denied" message.

Comment: @AlexD. I don't know much about docker. You might want to open a new question regarding the issue.